# How can you access the head of an iframe embedded by JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

My client is using Tockify to add an events widget to his site.  It uses an embed script to create the iframe on the page. Here is the section of html in the actual html file:

```
<div id="events" class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
          <h1 id="h1">EVENTS</h1>
          <div data-tockify-component="mini" data-tockify-calendar="djkayrich"></div>
          <script data-cfasync="false" data-tockify-script="embed" src="events_widget.php"></script>
     </div>
</div>
```

When I load the page here is what that section looks like live in the browser:

[image]

There is a method I found with other iframes using PHP where you can save the html of the iframe src to your own php files and use str_replace to modify the head of the embedded iframe document to add your own stylesheet to style the contents.  Here is what that looks like:

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('https://podomatic.com/embed/html5/podcast/5510683?autoplay=false&square=true');
$content = str_replace('</title>','</title><base href="https://podomatic.com/embed/html5/podcast/" />', $content);
$content = str_replace('</head>','<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.djkayrich.com/assets/stylesheets/kayrich_podcasts_iframe.css" /></head>', $content);
echo $content;

?>
```

This method only works if I actually write the iframe on the base html page.  The section I am trying to modify from Tockify has me write a div and script tag.  No actual iframe but that gets generated on load by the javascript.  I tried to add to the embed js some code to access the head of the iframe but when I do this it accesses the head of the whole website not the iframe content.

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('https://public.tockify.com/browser/embed.js');
$content .= 'alert(document.head.innerHTML)';
echo $content;

?>
```

Does anyone have any idea of how I can manipulate the head of this iframe to inject my own css?

Comment: your site and iframe are same domain?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is not possible. You should look into the customization options they offer. https://tockify.com/i/customizer?tab=basics

Comment: It's not possible. For all intents and purposes, an iframe is equivalent to a separate tab. If you have control over the iframe, you can use `postMessage` to communicate between them, but you can not directly modify it via JavaScript.

Comment: @Eddie The trick I found with the other iframe does that since technically the contents of the file were saved to a page on my domain.  It's trickier with this js setup.